# Pie chart in Google Sheets has 100% one item

Tags: google-sheets

How can I create a pie chart in Google Sheets from 2 cells?

| Total cash | Total funds |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 60 |

When I create a chart it comes out as 100% one item.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chart editor, check the box: `swich rows/columns` or try to arrange the cells differently.

[image: pie]